# Docker-Compose for ASP.Net Core on Windows Containers

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to build an ASP.Net Core container on Windows base because I would like to test some AD Queries. On the same time I would like to share my development folder with the container so that I can edit files on the fly without recompiling the container each time. On Linux and laravel it worked quite fine with this:

```
     volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
```

On windows my docker file looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:latest AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]
```

and my composer like this:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  #ASP
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80"
    container_name: app
    working_dir: /app
    #restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\
        target: c:\app
    entrypoint: ["dotnet", "project.dll"]
```

As soon I add the volumes part I receive following message:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Without volumes I can at least run it normally but trying out something is kind of terrible ,)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

Update
I found the error. The app data after it is mounted is empty but should contain the app files.

```
C:\app>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 76CF-40D6

 Directory of C:\app

05/03/2020  11:34 AM    <DIR>          .
05/03/2020  11:34 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/01/2020  10:25 PM               162 appsettings.Development.json
05/01/2020  10:25 PM               192 appsettings.json
05/03/2020  11:34 AM           106,534 project.deps.json
05/03/2020  11:34 AM             9,216 project.dll
05/03/2020  11:34 AM           169,984 project.exe
05/03/2020  11:34 AM             1,864 project.pdb
05/03/2020  11:34 AM               224 project.runtimeconfig.json
05/03/2020  11:34 AM            35,840 project.Views.dll
05/03/2020  11:34 AM             3,544 project.Views.pdb
05/03/2020  11:34 AM               490 web.config
05/03/2020  11:34 AM    <DIR>          wwwroot
              10 File(s)        328,050 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  21,299,187,712 bytes free
```

Still my question would be, what do I need to change to have the app folder on my local disk?

---

Another update. 
I got the folder mounted, but unfortunately, different as Lavavel, I cannot edit the files on the fly, even if I changed everything to Razor. Maybe I have to add somehow another folder to the container... At the moment I am thinking the best way is to install the IIS locally...

---

Update, it finally works. I ll update tomorrow the solution.

Comment: "Any idea what I am doing wrong?" You shouldn't copy your source code to the Docker container at all. Run `dotnet publish` on your development machine or a CI machine, and then only deploy the published artifacts to Docker containers. `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest` is exactly the base image for such scenarios, as it does not have .NET Core SDK bundled, and will not be able to run `dotnet publish`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is my explanation what I had to change.

1. Activating Razor

   - In the project.csproj file:

   PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.3" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"

   - In the launchsettings.json

   "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
2. Change to Razor

   - Editing the Startup.cs

   services.AddControllersWithViews()
       .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

   ```
       services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
       {
           var libraryPath = Path.GetFullPath(
               Path.Combine(HostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "..", "ProjectFolderName"));
           options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(libraryPath));                
       });
   ```

(Important is the project folder name)

3. Add the project folder to the container

   volumes:
         - .\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1:c:\app:ro
         - .:c:\project